# How to populate input fields with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to write a simple calculator html page where I ask for two numbers in separate text boxes, have the user click a button and then the result gets stored into a third text box. I'm trying to using PHP to resolve this but can't seem to display it the way I want.
the echo line works fine, but I don't want that;

From HTML

```
     <form action="Add.php" method="get">
        <input for='num1' type="text"  name="num1" />
        <input for='num2' type="text" name="num2" />

        <input type="submit" value="Add Them" />
        <input type="text" name="AnswerBx" id="SumTotalTxtBx"/>
    </form>
```

Add.php

```
     <?php 
        $num1 = $_GET["num1"];
        $num2 = $_GET['num2'];
        $sum = $num1+$num2;
        //echo "$num1 + $num2 = $sum";

        document.getElementById("SumTotalTxtBx").value = $sum;
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain more? I think you aren't wrapping the javascript code inside a <script> tag

Answer (score 8):

You can't mix PHP and JavaScript like that! One is run on the server the other on the client.

You have to echo the value into the value attribute of the text boxes like so

```
<input type="text" value="<?PHP echo $sum; ?>" />
```

Comment: That's how I do it :) I'd prefer a way that looks neater in my code though

Comment: for a simple calculator, that's as good enough. For complex sites, I use template engine like http://www.raintpl.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing PHP and Javascript here, go back to the PHP manual at : http://php.net/manual and read out how php works and interacts with the user.

Javascript is basicaly run on the client side while PHP is run on the server. You REQUEST php something and it returns a new HTML page for you.

That being said, its a too broad topic to help you fix your error.

Good luck

Comment: The problem is that this goes farther than just telling the user to echo the value in the input tag, but you can take that route too.

Comment: Do you mean the problem of mixing the two? Or other possible solutions like the JS ones or AJAX?

Comment: The user doesn't understand the basic principles of how to use PHP correctly, therefore it goes over the scope of this site or else you'll get thousands of "echo" not working requests per day. Which in turn would kill this wonderful site. We are not here to teach users how to use PHP but fix problems regarding existing valid code...

Answer (score 0):

Using **jQuery** you can solve it without doing post back's at Server like this

```
var num1 = parseInt($("input:text[name='num1']"));
var num2 = parseInt($("input:text[name='num2']"));
$('input:text#SumTotalTxtBx').val(num1+num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so PHP is awesomeness, but all of it's calculations are performed on the serverside, not the clientside. Using AJAX, you *can* execute some of the PHP code back against the server, but I think you may be more interested in javascript for your calculator.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function calculateSum()
{
    num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

    sum = num1 + num2;

    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
</script>
<body>
<input id="num1" type="text"/><br/>
<input id="num2" type="text"/><br/>
<button onclick="calculateSum()">Submit!</button>
<span id="sum">..the sum is..</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript is really quite simple, and is absolutely wonderful when programming anything on the clientside. If you want to learn more, I'd suggest you read up on [javascript over at w3schools](http://w3schools.com/js/default.asp)! I hope that helps!!